# How to detect mobile number in HTML device

Tags: html, web

I want to auto detect the mobile device number from my HTML5 web site developed for mobile devices. Can we do this or it is not possible

Comment: Do you mean telephone number or the IMEI Number?

Comment: Telephone number, sorry i was not clear

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<a href="tel:+ccxxxxxxxxx">Phone Number</a>
```

where `cc` is the country code and `xxxxxxxxx` is the rest of the phone number

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate related to [Can a mobile Web app obtain Android device identification information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931252/can-a-mobile-web-app-obtain-android-device-identification-information)

And the answer is: this is not possible, you'll have to write your own solution for user identification.